# Find the number of n- digit ternary sequences with at least one instance of consecutive 0's.

Tags: combinatorics

I know how to do this problem with binary sequences but I have no idea how to start with ternary sequences. Any help would be great!

Comment: Similar techniques should apply here.  Hint:  it's easier, I think to count the ternary sequences with no $00$ term, and then subtract that number from the total number $3^n$.

Comment: Okay, so something like an = an-1 + an-2 + an-2 +3^n-3? And from there solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: Well...I'm not sure about that expression.  But, yes, there is a linear regression involved.  Are you meant to get a closed form or is the regression enough?

Comment: The closed form.

Comment: Ok.  Still, I'd do it the way I suggested.  Solve for $T_n$ the number of ternary strings that do not contain $00$.  That's a nice linear recursion.  Then the answer you want is just $3^n-T_n$.

Comment: Alight I'll try that out. Thanks for the help!